# Youtube Android Player API 4k livestreams are not working: Error screen presenter should be present

Tags: android-youtube-api

I'm using **YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2**.

**Youtube app version 16.43.34**

Most of videos/livestreams are working fine but for live streams labeled as 4k I get an error:

`E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error screen presenter should be present`

I'm using a fragment(but it's also reproduced for view or standalone player):

`player.loadVideo("skWfeXhHsbY");`

Just some ids which were live and were throwing same error(all taken from search for live 4k streams):

- U2Pb3rhwaGg
- jMr62INX0Rc
- uDS-7PruNEA

Is there any way to make this work? Thanks

Comment: This mentioned `skWfeXhHsbY` video is no longer a live stream, though still cannot be played:
 - `onLoaded` is called from `PlayerStateChangeListener` but then it just hangs there.

Comment: Getting same error YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error screen presenter should be present for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79DijItQXMM

Comment: I got this error for video, which wasn't available for my country.